# How to set Vim to terminal's sixteen-colors?

Tags: linux, vim, colors, terminal, linux-mint

Recently I had been able to get Vim to mirror all of my terminal's colors. Vim looked and felt how I wanted it. However, when I updated Vim last night to the latest version, 8.0.577, it stripped all of that out and gave me back the wretched color-scheme I once had.

I am running Linux Mint and use the standard terminal emulator that comes included. Is there any code I can place in my "~/.vimrc" that would make Vim mirror my terminal's sixteen-colors, thus standardizing how I use Vim in the future?

Comment: I suggest you to give a bit more information on your problem. It is not very clear... What's your colorscheme?

Comment: I have no colorscheme. I'm simply using the colors from my terminal's palette. Vim defaults to several colors that I can't change in my terminal's palette. I had that changed for awhile, but the recent update of Vim brought back the default colors I can't change.

Comment: You should know that colorschemes also use colors from your terminal's palette...

Comment: I have no "colorscheme" setup in my "~/.vimrc". I'm not interested in the "colorscheme" feature of "~/.vimrc". I'm trying to simply sync my terminal's palette completely to Vim so I can more easily maintain/control my syntax's colors.

Comment: So you use the `highlight` command, right?

Comment: I also got this working at one point and it was awesome because I could adjust the colors just by changing them in the terminal settings, but I can't seem to get it back either. I tried the t_Co=16, but that didn't help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Interesting question, since most people have the opposite problem where they want more colours but only get the standard 16... Anyway, try this in your `.vimrc` or from the `:` prompt:

```
set t_Co=16
```

Comment: Thanks! Might have to work w/ it a bit, but this was the answer.

Answer (score 0):

I did some digging with colour schemes, and it seems "colorscheme default" will also allow people to turn off colour schemes. That did not even exist back when I was last using X.